# LibreOffice/Excel Table Calculation Formula

Tags: excel, macros, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-base

I have three Columns in one sheet. **Col1** Have Combination Of **Col2** Values, I need to replace **Col1** Value as equal Of **COl2** = **col3** Value.

Is there Any Formula to do this in LibreOffice Calculation.

Actual Table:

```
Col1  | col2 | Col3 
  A   |  A   |  X
  C   |  B   |  Y
  A   |  C   |  Z
  B   |      | 
  A   |      |
  B   |      | 
  C   |      | 
  A   |      | 
  C   |  
  B   |
```

Expected Output:

```
Col1  | col2 | Col3 
  X   |  A   |  X
  Z   |  B   |  Y
  X   |  C   |  Z
  Y   |      | 
  X   |      |
  Y   |      | 
  Z   |      | 
  X   |      | 
  Z   |  
  Y   |
```

Thanks In Advance, I am struggling For long days in this.

Comment: Lets say Col1 starts with column `A`. Then simple put `=C2` in column `A` and drag it down.

Comment: Col1 Have Redundancy of Col2 Values. For example Col1 Contains A I need To replace All A as X in Col1.

Comment: Just a formatting tip. Please do not capitalize words randomly. It becomes harder to read.

Comment: I need A formula For:   A1 = B1:B3 If its Match In n Number I need To replace A1 as Cn

Comment: Does `col2` and `col3` only has 3 rows?

Comment: Yes, It has only three rows. and col2 is redundancy of col1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125088/discussion-between-kamal-kannan-and-sathish-krishnan).

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's a work around. You would like to change `A->X, B->Y and C->Z` in `col1`. Create a `col4` with the formula

```
=CHAR(CODE(A1)+23)
```

This offsets the `A` by 23 characters that will be `X` and therefore, `B` and `C`s with `Y` and `Z`.